# how not to fall into infinite loop with viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with cells and header. header consists of two views in a stack view. I set a specific height of the header every time the tableView width change.

The question: how to not fall into infinite loop? here is the code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    guard let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { [weak self] (_) in
        self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
        if (self?.filtersView.isHidden)! {
            self?.filtersViewHeight.constant = .leastNormalMagnitude
            self?.stackView.bounds.size.height = 45
        } else {
            self?.filtersViewHeight.constant = 100
            self?.stackView.bounds.size.height = 45 + (self?.filtersViewHeight.constant)!
        }
        }, completion: { [weak self] (_) in
            flowLayout.invalidateLayout()

            self?.tableView.endUpdates() <---- this is wrong, as it forces the infinite loop.
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take this functionality out of `viewWIllLayoutSubviews` and put it into it's own function. Call that function for your animation, and call the `setNeedsLayout` in your animation block. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` can be called for many reasons.

The tableView `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` notify the view that the tableView, or parts of it need to be redrawn, so it will call `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: yes, I see your point and this is totally correct! It works now, thanks! Will set it to the correct answer in a couple of mins